# How to align the content between two very simple tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lists, align, acronyms

I want to create a list of acroynms, consisted of two tables, separated by "List 1" and "List 2"

The generated image is as follows

[image]

However, as you can see the list is not exactly aligned across the tables

It would be much better if they were aligned at the red line shown:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Code is attached below.

```
%% *** Add any desired options. ***
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{chapter}
\begin{document}



\chapter{ list of acroynms}

\section*{List 1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $NM$ & Nano-fracture-induced Microfibers\\
    $HN$ & Hot Nanoencoders
\end{tabular}

\section*{List 2}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    $ABCD$ & Alpha Bromide Carbon Dioxide\\
    $EFGH$ & Erbium-Fractured Gallium Hydrate 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using math mode for getting italic text?

Comment: @clemens No haha, they were originally math symbols, I just changed them to letters for this purpose but forgot to remove the $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set a fixed width for the first column.

Do you know that there are packages dedicated to the acroynms (see [here](https://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/), for example)?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{chapter}
\begin{document}



    \chapter{ list of acroynms}

    \section*{List 1}
    \begin{tabular}{p{34pt}l}
        $NM$ & Nano-fracture-induced Microfibers\\
        $HN$ & Hot Nanoencoders
    \end{tabular}

    \section*{List 2}
    \begin{tabular}{p{34pt}l}
        $ABCD$ & Alpha Bromide Carbon Dioxide\\
        $EFGH$ & Erbium-Fractured Gallium Hydrate 
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way without tables would be a simple list (using a customized description environment with `enumitem`).

[image: list]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{chapter}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ list of acroynms}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=4em,font=\mdseries}
\section*{List 1}
\begin{description}
    \item[$NM$] Nano-fracture-induced Microfibers
    \item[$HN$] Hot Nanoencoders
\end{description}

\section*{List 2}
\begin{description}
    \item[$ABCD$] Alpha Bromide Carbon Dioxide
    \item[$EFGH$] Erbium-Fractured Gallium Hydrate 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```